# HasManyThrough Eloquent Relationship, Laravel 5.6, 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

i have three tables: articles, images & article_images

i want to output $article->file

it was very simple in laravel 5.0

$article->article_images->file;

But now they removed this function, also i am using the output with vuejs.

**articles**

id - integer

name - string

**article_images**

id - integer

article_id - integer

image_id - integer

**images**

id - integer

file - string

Comment: Did you read the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)? Everything is well explained there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a relationship between article and article_images

```
public functon images() {
   return $this->belongsTo('...\ArticleImage');
}
```

After that you can return the article with the relation

```
return Article::find($id)->with('images');
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

First u Must added relationships in ur models, 
So in this case, u have article has many images and one image belongs to many articles so u should remove the article_images and add this functions in ur models (Article and images)

```
// In Article model 
public function Images()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Image');
}


// In Images model 
public function Article()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
```

After that u can use below code for get all images for preferred article
for ex :

`$images = Article::first()->images();`

Answer (score 0):

*NOT: HasManyThrough*

**BUT: belongsToMany**

Solved the problem!

Read the following code:

```
    class Article extends Model
    {
        public function images()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Image','article_images','image_id','article_id');
        }

    }
```